# Why Twitter bootsrap is called bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just by curiosity, why twitter called it like that ?

I tried to find an answer in the web, but no body explains why.

Comment: Because, 2 guys who were worked at `Twitter` developed this.

Answer (score 3):

Why did someone name the moon, "the moon"?

But maybe it's not that difficult...bootstrap is the base/core CSS you start with to get going to build "successively more complex" sites, so that would tie into the following definition for bootstrapping:

"Bootstrapping can also refer to the development of successively more complex, faster programming environments. The simplest environment will be, perhaps, a very basic text editor (e.g., ed) and an assembler program. Using these tools, one can write a more complex text editor, and a simple compiler for a higher-level language and so on, until one can have a graphical IDE and an extremely high-level programming language."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping

Ultimately, however, only its developers know what they were thinking when they named it so this is not truly an answerable question, which is why you got voted down so much.